# ¿Se puede poner una variable en un Array que viene de mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, array

Un array se puede crear de la siguiente forma ¿cierto?:

```
 $array1 = "uno"; 
 $array2 = "dos"; 
 $array3 = "tres"; 
 $miarray = array($array1, $array2, $array3);
 echo  $miarray[0] . ", " . $miarray[1] . " y " . $miarray[2]; 
 //Obteniendo: uno, dos y tres
 //O también así:
 $miarray = array("prueba1", "prueba2", "prueba3");
 echo  $miarray[0] . ", " . $miarray[1] . " y " . $miarray[2];
 //Obteniendo: prueba1, "prueba2 y prueba3

 //De mi base de datos viene:
 arreglo
 "prueba1".","."prueba2"
 //también he probado con:
 "prueba1", "prueba2"
 //Como dato el campo es de tipo TEXT
```

Aquí una imagen de la fila:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Como puedo hacer lo siguiente? Me gustaría traer el array guardado en mysql y poderlos obtener de la siguiente forma, comprendiendo lo explicado de un array:

```
 include(coneccion.php)
 mysqli_set_charset($conecta,"utf8");
 $result = $conecta->query("SELECT arreglo FROM bd WHERE id = 'libros'");
 $filas = $result->fetch_assoc();
 $arreglo = $filas['arreglo'];
 echo $arreglo; //Obteniendo: "prueba1", "prueba2", "prueba3"
 //ahora los inserto en el array
 $arreglo1 = array(arreglo);
 echo  $arreglo1[0] . ", " . $arreglo1y[1] . " y " . $arreglo1[2];
 //y me gustaría obtener: prueba1, "prueba2 y prueba3
```

¿Como puedo obtener este resultado? ¿como puedo hacer para que array me detecte las comas?

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115092/discussion-on-question-by-abner-se-puede-poner-una-variable-en-un-array-que-vie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En `mysqli`, lo que hace `query()` es devolverte un recurso con los datos. Luego puedes usar algún método (como `fetch_assoc()`), para leer ese recurso.

Generalmente los resultados se recorren dentro de un bucle y ahí decides qué hacer:

1. Mostrar los datos si no necesitas portarlos a otra parte o
2. Guardarlos en una variable para portarlos a otra parte (por ejemplo hacer `return` en una función) o usarlos a posteriori.

Veamos ambos casos:

### Mostrar in situ

```
#OJO: he llamado $fila a la variable (coherencia), cada iteracción es una fila
while ( $fila = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    #Dado que se requiere mostrar in situ no tiene sentido guardar en variables
    echo $fila['arreglo'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

### Mostrar/usar a posteriori

Crearías un array vacío de entrada, y lo vas llenando dentro del while. Luego lo retornas.

```
$mData=array();
#OJO: he llamado $fila a la variable (coherencia), cada iteracción es una fila
while ( $fila = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
    #Aquí, cada fila se guardará en $mData
    $mData[]= $fila;
}
#Mostrar/usar $mData a posteriori
```

---

### Crear un array con datos separados por algún carácter

Si lo que quieres es crear un array con datos separados por coma u otro caracter, puedes usar [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php).

Por ejemplo:

```
$datobd='"prueba1", "prueba2", "prueba3"';
$array=explode(",",$datobd);

#Test
print_r($array);
```

La salida sería:

```
(
    [0] => "prueba1"
    [1] =>  "prueba2"
    [2] =>  "prueba3"
)
```

Como ves, `$array` sería un arreglo con cada dato por separado. Pero eso implica que tendrías que seguir trabajando los datos, por ejemplo, quitarle las comillas con una función de reemplazo. Hablamos ya de dos funciones adicionales (`explode()` y una de reemplazo) para seguir *tratando* unos datos que deberían obtenerse de forma natural desde la base de datos.

En muchos casos, como comenté ampliamente en la pregunta, hay que aprovechar las ventajas que ofrecen las bases de datos: modelo relacional, funciones de agregación, `JOIN`, etc. Guardar datos agrupados, aunque parezca más práctico, lo único que hace es complicar el tratamiento de los datos y sobre cargar el código. Además, el mantenimiento, la integridad, el control de errores, etc. es más difícil.